# How to iterate through an array from a specific point to the end of array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops

I need to iterate through an array starting at a specific point in the array to the very end of it.

For example:

```
<% @posts[6.."To the very end of array"].each do |post| %>
 <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

Here is a more complete example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% if post == @posts.first && !params[:page] %>
    <div class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet">
      <%= render partial: 'posts/main_post', locals: {post: post} %>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-phone visible-tablet">
      <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: 'posts/add_post' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @posts[1..5].each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
<%= render partial: 'posts/add2_post' %>

<% @posts[6..11].each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
<%= render partial: 'posts/add3_post' %>

<% @posts[12.."To the very end of array"]each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length of the array, like so:

```
<% @posts[6..@posts.length].each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

Technically you should be doing `length-1` but that can be tedious to type, and if you supply a number larger than the bounds of the array, Ruby will just not go past it anyways.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to mark it as the answer for any future visitors.